# export Nintegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, export, list-manipulation

I use the following `NIntegrate` to calculate my integral.
When I use, `Export`, I get the f(r) value in the text file but not r. How can I export {r,f[r]} using `NIntegrate`, `Table` and `Export` ?

Here my code

```
mu0 := 4*Pi*10^(-7)
R := 7.6                                                              

Ms := 3.41                                                            

Hp := 0.25/mu0/
  10^9                                                                

DeltaMs := 
 0.25/mu0/10^9                                                        

A := 8.2*10^(-11)                                                     

(*DD:=0.45*10^(-3)                              DM constant in J/m^2*)


lD[DD_] := 10^9*2*DD*mu0/Ms^2
lD[0.00045]
lM = 10^9*Sqrt[2*A*mu0/Ms^2]
h2[Hp_, q_, RH_] := Hp^2*RH^0/(1 + q^2*RH^2)^2
Heff[q_, H_, A_] := H + 2*A/(Ms/mu0)*q^2*10^(18)                
p[q_, H_, A_] := 
 Ms/Heff[q, H, 
   A]                                                                 
nenner[q_, H_, DD_, A_] := 1 - p[q, H, A]^2*lD[DD]^2*q^2
chi[Hp_, q_, H_, DD_, RH_, 
  A_] := (4*p[q, H, A]^3*h2[Hp, q, RH]*lD[DD]*q)/nenner[q, H, DD, A]^2 
p[q_, H_] := Ms/Heff[q, H]     
nennerav[q_, H_, DD_] := 1 - p[q, H]^2*lD[DD]^2*q^2
FFav[q_, H_, DD_] := (4*p[q, H]^3*h2[q]*lD[DD]*q)/nennerav[q, H, DD]^2 
norm = NIntegrate[
  chi[1675.58, q, 5, 0.0004489, 7.6, 8.19*10^(-11)]*1*q^2, {q, 0.001, 
   100}]
results = 
 Table[1/norm*
   NIntegrate[
    chi[1675.58, q, 5, 0.0004489, 7.6, 8.19*10^(-11)]*
     SphericalBesselJ[0, q*r]*q^2, {q, 0.001, 100}, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> GaussKronrodRule}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4], {r, 0, 30}]
Export["Cr.txt", results, "Table"]
```

Comment: Add `r` in your table: `Table[{r, 1/norm*NIntegrate[...]},{r,0,30}]`, then your `Export[...]` should give what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure that I correctly understand what are you after. I think you want this:
`results =Table[{r,1/norm*NIntegrate[chi[1675.58, q, 5, 0.0004489, 7.6, 8.19*10^(-11)]*SphericalBesselJ[0, q*r]*q^2, {q, 0.001, 100},Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}, PrecisionGoal -> 4]}, {r, 0, 30}]`. As a minor correction, `"GaussKronrodRule"` is a string and must be written in quotes.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, it works and thanks for the improvement